# Blender [2.91] Liquid simulation not filling container

Tags: fluid-simulation

I am trying to fill a container from bottom to top. I have a cylinder at the bottom that has -3m/s velocity on the z-axis (shooting towards the bottom of the container to get a sort of a splash effect). The animation takes about 400 Frames. My issue is that the container only seems to fill up to around 40%, and than it stops filling. I can still see the water moving and the animation lasts another 80 frames or so but the liquid does not rise anymore. Changing the velocity and the resolution does not change this.

How do I make it so that it fills the container? Now it just really fills 40% and than tha animation kind off "floats" at that level untill the final frame is reached. I cannot seem to find out how I make it just continue filling to frame 400.

Any help will be greatly appreacated.

Comment: please add your .blend file so we can help you. Just helping "theoretically" is often a waste of time because the "helper" cannot test his answer...

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out.

1. Lower The Viscosity of your liquid
2. Make the source size bigger
3. Make sure your source has enough room to "spout out" the liquid
4. Use modular bake so you can finetune settings without having to bake everything all over all the time
5. Bake the mesh